# How to access recursively to end nested objects in java

Tags: java, recursion

I want to access other nested objects recursively using last object which is "mul1" because it contains all other objects. But it returns only one object. It is not a Vector like object. Please any one can give a solution for access these nested objects. [image]

```
    FormulaElement varX=new VariableElement("X");
    FormulaElement c7=new ConstantElement(7);       
    FunctionElement plus=new PlusFunctionElement();
    plus.addArgument(varX); 
    plus.addArgument(c7);


    FormulaElement c2=new ConstantElement(2);       
    FunctionElement min=new MinusFunctionElement();
    min.addArgument(varX);
    min.addArgument(c2);


    FunctionElement mul1=new MultipleFunctionElement();
    mul1.addArgument(plus);
    mul1.addArgument(min);
```

EDIT:

Formula element does not contains any method yet. I want to add this recursive method to find nested elements in FormulaElement class. this is my FunctionElement class :

```
public class FunctionElement extends FormulaElement {

private Vector<FormulaElement> arguments;

public FunctionElement() {
    arguments = new Vector<FormulaElement>();
}

public void addArg(FormulaElement element) {
    arguments.add(element);
}

public void setArgs(Vector<FormulaElement> arguments) {
    this.arguments = arguments;
}

public Vector<FormulaElement> getArgs() {
    return arguments;
}

public FormulaElement getArg(int i) {
    return arguments.get(i);
}

public String toString() {
    return this.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: what do you mean it "returns only one object" what does? what method?

Comment: Debugger.. Debugger.. Debugger..

Comment: It should have something like `mul1.getArguments()`. Lookup the class or try autocompletion of `mul1.|`.

Comment: I hardcoded what inside that method. assume that method returns only "mul1" object. but it contains all other nested objects. This "mul1" object contains both "plus" and "min" objects. "plus" object contains both "varX" and "c7" objects. "min" object contains both "varX" and "c2" objects.

Comment: You should add the code of FormulaElement class, it would be easier to understand your problem

Comment: Please see edited contents.

Answer (score 1):

### KEEP TRACK OF CALLER AND PASSED ARGUMENT

*Well probably not the best solution* but you can use `ArrayList` ( *Or probably something else to follow up this idea* ) to keep track of `caller` and `argument`.

*For Example* you can change your `addArgument` method to `addArgument(caller,argument);` and after that inside `argument` you can add both this object to your class level variable `ArrayList<Object[]>`.

*But it will be your duty to check whether there should not be duplication in `ArrayList`.*

*You can also create separate class to do the same.*